# XML File create using write XML and write the Data set into it

Tags: c#, xml

I want to check path for a xml file and if it does not exist, then i want to create a new xml file and write my data set content into it.xml file is creating in my local machine. but the file does not contain any column headers.xml file content is like below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="true"?>
<DS xmlns="TaxTableNamespace"/>
```

here is my code

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
DataTable TaxTable = new DataTable();
string xmlFilename = @"D:\test.xml";

public DataSet CreateDynamicDataSet()
{
 DataSet ds = new DataSet(); 
 DataColumn col1 = new DataColumn("Type");
 DataColumn col2 = new DataColumn("Rec_Seq");
 DataColumn col3 = new DataColumn("Income");
 DataColumn col4 = new DataColumn("Amount");
 DataColumn col5 = new DataColumn("Percentage");
 DataColumn col6 = new DataColumn("IncomeTT");
 TaxTable.Columns.Add(col1);
 TaxTable.Columns.Add(col2);
 TaxTable.Columns.Add(col3);
 TaxTable.Columns.Add(col4);
 TaxTable.Columns.Add(col5);
 TaxTable.Columns.Add(col6);
 ds.Tables.Add(TaxTable);
 ds.AcceptChanges();
 ds.WriteXml(@"D:\test.xml");
 return ds;    
 }
```

Comment: You haven't added any data, what result are you expecting?

Comment: it should show column headers right?

Comment: No, there isn't a concept of column headers in xml. You can have empty elements, but there won't be any created automatically. You can write the schema by also passing an XMLWriteMode parameter but I don't think that is what you are talking about.